# Everyone travelling has an Irish passport except baby who has a British passport, is this going to be a a problem since the UK left the EU?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, eu, eu-family-member

I, my husband and two sons have Irish passports. However we couldn't get one for our baby in time so had to get a British one for him.

I believe there are two lines when showing your passports EU citizens and non EU citizens. Is this going to cause problems for us or can we still take him through with us?

Comment: The two lanes are "EU/EEA/Swiss passports" and "all passports."  Anyone can go to the all passports queue.  But EU citizens can take their close family with them to the EU queue regardless of citizenship, as Mark Johnson says in his answer.

Answer (score 14):

Family members of EU Citizens, who are 3rd country nationals, may use the same lane as EU Citizens when travelling together, so this will not be a problem.

Comment: Not on the now ubiquitous automated gates though. (Not that this applies to someone travelling with a baby, who wouldn't be able to use them anyway.)